# How to Redirect from Servlet page to Different two Jsp Page

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am Making a Project Online Exam Management System.
There are Three Admin, Faculty and Student 
Admin and Faculty both Can Insert and Update and Delete Subject and Questions 
I want make the Servlet When Admin Add or Remove Subject or Questions Servlet Must be back Redirect to Admin Home page and When Faculty Add or Remove Subject or Questions  Page Must be Redirect to Faculty Home Page

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `User` class with field like `typeOfUser`. Then while registering user you can populate this field in your `RegistrationServlet` on the basis of who is getting registered. eg: admin, student, faculty.

Now once you have `typeOfUser` information captured, whenever user logs-in add `typeOfUser` in the `Session` eg: `session.setAttribute("typeOfUser", "Admin")`.

When Faculty/Admin Add or Remove Subject or Questions, check `typeOfUser` and redirect him/her to respective page. Code snippet could be like below:

```
String typeOfUser = (String)session.getAttribute("typeOfUser");
if(typeOfUser.equals("admin")){
   response.sendRedirect("admin-home.jsp");
}else if(typeOfUser.equals("faculty")){
    response.sendRedirect("faculty-home.jsp");
}
```

Comment: Ok Thanke You, I will Implement this Concept in My Project

Comment: @Mohammed Afnan Shaikh If this answer works for you then you can accept the answer so that it can help others too in Stack Overflow community.